# UITableView reloadData crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I added CustomImageView to the UITableViewCell.

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell1"] autorelease];
    }
    CustomImageView *customIV = [[CustomImageView alloc] init];
    [cell.contentView addSubView:customIV];
    [customIV release];
```

But when I try to reload tableview, the error occurs.

error call stack is same as follows.

[image]

Output string is as follows.

> -[CustomImageView superview]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1f848f30

Comment: try this: [cell.contentView addSubview:customIV];

Comment: Can you post the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`'s full code ?

Comment: @ttotto You need to add the subview on the cell's content view, not the cell itself. See iManan's answer below.

Comment: @ttotto, if you are ARC remove autorelease at the end of cell allocation line.

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti If ARC was being used, you couldn't have a call to autorelease so this code must be using MRC.

Comment: This issue happens if you are dequeuing the cell and outside the `if` condition you are doing an autorelease which causes the cell to be released while reusing. Since you haven't shared the complete code, it is difficult to confirm that.

Comment: @ttotto: Is CustomImageView is your row background image? if yes, then why do you add CustomImageView in each cell separately. You can set it using background view

Comment: Moreover agreed with ACB

Comment: try this: CustomImageView *customIV = [[[CustomImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
[cell.contentView addSubView:customIV];

Answer (score 1):

```
CustomImageView *customIV = [[CustomImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
[cell.contentView addSubView:customIV];
```

It's done with me when I've released memory.
So according to me, No need to release, because it'll deallocated memory.

Hopefully, it'll help you.
Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, customIV would leak in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **Comment** this line`[customIV release];` & run , it should not crash while reloading data.

The reason behind this is everytime it tries to create new custom view & releases it, so causes extra load on system & crash occurs.

Comment: your idea is nice but it helpful when OP release obj  of customIV more then one time ..here OP release it only one time :)

Comment: I know it releases object one time, but it will release object & will create object everytime in multiplication of content in table rows. So my basic question is why to add same CustomImageView in each cell?

Answer (score 1):

You only want to add the image once to each cell. Change your code to this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell1"] autorelease];
        CustomImageView *customIV = [[CustomImageView alloc] init];
        [cell.contentView addSubView:customIV];
        [customIV release];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

If this doesn't work then you need to show your complete `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. By only showing part of your code you make it difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur because each time `CustomImageView` object created when your `cell` created.

so, best way is first initialize object of `CustomImageView` then create your `UITableView`

such like,

`CustomImageView *customIV` put it in your `.h file` and then `@synthesize` it in `.m File`

(put this code above `UITableView`)

```
self.customIV = [[CustomImageView alloc] init];
```

Then create `UITableView`

```
self.tablView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
.
.
.
.
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  only add `[cell.contentView addSubView:self.customIV];`

Comment: This doesn't work if the custom image view needs to appear in more than one row.

Comment: @rmaddy- ya but each time u use instance of CustomImageView in cell

Comment: A single view can't appear in more than one parent view. Therefore it is impossible to have a single instance if `CustomImageView` and add it to more than one row in the table.

Comment: I have no idea what your last comment means.

Comment: @iPatel, That is wrong and you shouldn't be doing it. This is one the most common and basic mistake people do in their code.

Comment: @ACB, I have to add more than one custom image views in the table view cell. and I edited the question more detail. Please check the question and give me answer.

Comment: @ttotto, Can you please post the complete cellForRowAtIndexpath code? Do you have a dequeuereuse line? Are you releasing cell or its content view anywhere?